# How do I disable certain menu in editor user administrator page

Tags: admin-menu

How do I disable the **media**, **pages**, **comments**, **profile** and **tools** in editor user administrator page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your current active theme's functions.php file

```
 function remove_editor_menus()
    {
    global $menu;
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if($current_user->user_level < 10)
    {
        $restricted = array(__('Pages'),
                            __('Media'),
                            __('Comments'),
                            __('Tools'),                                
        );
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }// end while

    }// end if
}

    add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_editor_menus');
```